# complition error

Tags: magento-1.9

> [29-Jan-2019 11:02:16 UTC] PHP Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/home/prin/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php' for
>   inclusion
>   (include_path='/home/prin/public_html/includes/src:.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php')
>   in /home/prin/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 37 [29-Jan-2019
>   11:02:16 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in
>   /home/prin/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 54

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled compilation mode , thats way you see those errors.
Its suggested to experiment on a non-production system, as errors during compilation can white screen the store , like it may be happened to you .
After compiling the classes, Magento immediately put`s itself into “read from the compiled code” mode .

Disable compilation:
Go into

> includes/config.php
>   and comment this line

```
-#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```

To get rid of the error you need to disable the compilation in production , and clear the **include** directory created during compilation 
`includes/src`.

> php -f shell/compiler.php – clear

Comment: these two lines already exists there                                                                     define ('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');

Comment: ok so just comment the first line

Comment: thanks for your answer . it  solved my problem

Comment: @rajat Glad it is solved , can you accept it as an answer :) .